# Jenkins pre-build bash script before "Source Code Management"

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to execute a bash/shell script before the git "Source Code Management" kicks in on my project, so far the only way I see this working is using pipelines, is there a way to do this with a standard job?

What I want to achieve is to:

1. run `git stash`
2. run `git clean -f`
3. `rm -rf ./target ./project/target`
4. Allow standard "Source Code Management" flow to kick in to do a git pull

Any one has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For freestyle jobs check out the [Pre SCM BuildStep](https://plugins.jenkins.io/preSCMbuildstep/) plugin which allows build steps to be run before the SCM does any checkout.

> This plugin allows build step to run before SCM checkouts so that you perform any build step action on the the workspace, (cleanup, add a file with some settings for the SCM, etc) or call other scripts that need to be run before checking out from the SCM.

It will enable you to run a shell (or windows batch command) step before the SCM does the actual checkout, which is exactly what you want.